# VBoxManage setextradata command does not add avx2 to /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, avx2

Linux & VirtualBox noob here, so please go easy.

I've been running into problems compiling code with scipy in a VirtualBox 5.2 VM running Fedora 26 on my host Windows 10. The cryptic error output is "*Illegal instruction (core dumped)*". I believe the issue is scipy thinks the VM has AVX2 enabled when it doesn't (*grep flags /proc/cpuinfo* confirms that neither AVX nor AVX2 are enabled).

Going off of [this askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699077/how-to-enable-avx2-extensions-on-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-5), I tried running **VBoxManage setextradata $VMname VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2**. This seemed to work fine, and running **VBoxManage getextradata $VMname enumerate** even confirms the change (*Key: VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2* now shows up with a value of 1, as expected.)

But when I reboot my VM (or even when I reboot all of VirtualBox, just in case), *grep flags /proc/cpuinfo* shows that AVX and AVX2 are still absent from my flags. I don't understand why *VBoxManage* sees AVX2 now enabled but */proc/cpuinfo* does not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I will try one of those, thanks for the heads up